# How to avoid inserting duplicate data when inserting data into SQLite3 database using python?

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I use python 2.7 in Windows 7.

I have wrote a program to insert some data read from a text file into a SQLite3 database.

However, I found duplicate data inserted as there are duplicate data in the text file:

1  A

2  A

3  A

4  A

5  B

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Static_Analysis.db')

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE MAIN
   (
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   Error_List          CHAR(50),
   Warning_List        CHAR(50),
   Advice_List         CHAR(50),
   Total          CHAR(50),
   Note           CHAR(50));''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE ERROR_REPORT
   (
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL);''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE WARNING_REPORT
   (
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL);''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE ADVICE_REPORT
   (
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL);''')


file = open("summary.log",'r')

p1 = re.compile(r"[Error  ]")
p2 = re.compile("[Warning]")
p3 = re.compile(r"[Advice ]")

i = 1
m_i = 0
n_i = 0
p_i = 0
for line in file:

    if '[Error  ]' in line:       

      str = line.split(":")
      print str       
      conn.execute("INSERT INTO MAIN (NAME) VALUES (\"%s\")" % (str[0] 
           [9:]))
      conn.execute("INSERT INTO ERROR_REPORT (NAME) VALUES (\"%s\")" % 
          (str[-1]))
    elif '[Warning]' in line:


      str = line.split(":")
      conn.execute("INSERT INTO MAIN (NAME) VALUES (\"%s\")" % (str[0] 
            [9:]))
      conn.execute("INSERT INTO WARNING_REPORT (NAME) VALUES (\"%s\")" % 
        (str[-1]))
    elif '[Advice ]' in line:

      p_i = p_i + 1
      str = line.split(":")
      conn.execute("INSERT INTO MAIN (NAME) VALUES (\"%s\")" % (str[0] 
            [9:]))
      conn.execute("INSERT INTO ADVICE_REPORT (NAME) VALUES (\"%s\")" % 
           (str[-1]))
   else:
      i = i - 1
i = i + 1
```

I want to change the resulted table to:

1 A

2 B

How could I modify my code to avoid duplicate data to be insert into the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how much constraint you want to put on "avoiding duplicates".
Strictly speaking, you can avoid *any* duplicates by add constraints to your table:

```
CREATE TABLE MAIN
   (
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   Error_List          CHAR(50),
   Warning_List        CHAR(50),
   Advice_List         CHAR(50),
   Total          CHAR(50),
   Note           CHAR(50),
UNIQUE (NAME, Error_List, Warning_List, Advice_List, Total, Note) ON CONFLICT IGNORE
);
```

In this example I used a "table constraint", when the constraint spans multiple columns. You can also use a "column constraint" if you want to avoid a single value being duplicated.
For both cases, you can alter the conflict response, either `IGNORE`, `REPLACE`, `ABORT`, etc., depending on which behaviour you wish to elicit. These conflicts responses can also be set in the INSERT statements as,

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO MAIN (...) VALUES (...)
```

https://sqlite.org/lang.html